# Linking Passport.js and Mongo with my html site

Tags: html, css, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have written a website using HTML, CSS and Bootsrap. I have this other project that creates a login using MongoDB, Passport.js and Express. 
I have both projects finished I just need to merge them together but I have absolutely no idea on how to do it. Any help will be welcome.

My project: https://github.com/stevenarroyave/UPTAKE
The login/authentication project: https://github.com/stevenarroyave/Passport

I have no idea how to do this so any help will be welcome. If anyone is willing to fix this for me I'm willing to pay (paypal)
Thanks!

As a result i'd need to merge these 2 together and have a functional register/login form.

Comment: I really need this done by tomorrow 11am (BST). I'm willing to pay. Serious enquiries please. It's not a hard job since I just need to merge the two codes together. The code is all already written. Please help

Comment: Please check info https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex and describe what is wrong with your code. Also this site is not a coding service.